# Use textbox backcolor

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `textbox` in a form. I know how to change backcolor:

```
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
```

but now I want to use colors from the system tab in designer like *ScrollBar*. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either like:

```
TextBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.ScrollBar
```

or

```
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ScrollBar)
```

If you want to use a custom color:

```
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 100, 100, 100) 'with alpha
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100) 'without alpha
```

Answer (score 2):

The `SystemColors` class has a property for each of those, e.g.

```
TextBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.ScrollBar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. Unfortunatelly I do not have enough reputation to upvote one and choose the other.

Comment: You can send chocolate instead. ;-)